# Can't build an app for android platform in sencha touch 2

Tags: android, touch

I have searched the website to see if anyone had the same problem or similar but I couldn't find any relevant info to the issue I have. I am trying to compile a sencha touch 2 project to build an android app but it doesn't compile fully and successfully.

when I run this command,   `sencha app build native`  targeting android platform.

The error I get is as follows below:

```
[WRN]           [ [1000] : Yui Compressor Warning <> Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initial
izer =>                     }    ] :: ( C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\app\view\Blog.js => 24 : 21 )
[WRN]           [ [1000] : Yui Compressor Warning <> Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initial
izer =>                         }, ] :: ( C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\app\view\Main.js => 13 : 4 )
[WRN]           [ [1000] : Yui Compressor Warning <> Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initial
izer =>                         }, ] :: ( C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\app\view\Main.js => 17 : 4 )
[WRN]           [ [1000] : Yui Compressor Warning <> Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initial
izer =>             } ] :: ( C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\app\view\Main.js => 22 : 13 )
[INF]           Processing class inheritance graph
[INF]           Processing instantiation refereces to classes and aliases
[WRN]           [ [1000] : Yui Compressor Warning <> Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initial
izer =>                     }    ] :: ( C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\app\view\Blog.js => 24 : 21 )
[WRN]           [ [1000] : Yui Compressor Warning <> Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initial
izer =>                         }, ] :: ( C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\app\view\Main.js => 13 : 4 )
[WRN]           [ [1000] : Yui Compressor Warning <> Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initial
izer =>                         }, ] :: ( C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\app\view\Main.js => 17 : 4 )
[WRN]           [ [1000] : Yui Compressor Warning <> Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initial
izer =>             } ] :: ( C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\app\view\Main.js => 22 : 13 )
[INF]           Processing source dependencies
[WRN]           [ [1000] : Yui Compressor Warning <> Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initial
izer =>                         }, ] :: ( C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\app\view\Main.js => 13 : 4 )
[WRN]           [ [1000] : Yui Compressor Warning <> Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initial
izer =>                         }, ] :: ( C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\app\view\Main.js => 17 : 4 )
[WRN]           [ [1000] : Yui Compressor Warning <> Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initial
izer =>             } ] :: ( C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\app\view\Main.js => 22 : 13 )
[WRN]           [ [1000] : Yui Compressor Warning <> Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initial
izer =>                     }    ] :: ( C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\app\view\Blog.js => 24 : 21 )
[INF]           Concatenating output to file C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\build\GS\package\app.js
[INF]           Completed compilation.
[INF]           Processed remote file touch/sencha-touch.js
[INF]           Processed local file app.js
[INF]           Minified app.js
[INF]           Minified resources/css/app.css
[INF]           Generated app.json
[INF]           Embedded microloader into index.html
[ERR]           BUILD FAILED
[ERR]           com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERR]           C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:120: javax.script.ScriptException: sun.
org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (<Unknown source>#22(eval)
#132) in <Unknown source>#22(eval) at line number 132
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException.wrap(BasicException.java:43)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:104)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.dispatch(AbstractCommand.java:182)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.SenchaCommandTask.doExecute(SenchaCommandTask.java:58)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.BaseAntTask.execute(BaseAntTask.java:22)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)

[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:156)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:72)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.run(BasePluginCommands.java
:87)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.run(BasePluginCommands.java
:91)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BaseNamePathCommand.run(BasePluginCommands.ja
va:135)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:106)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:78)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:71)
[ERR]           Caused by: C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:126: The following error occ
urred while executing this line:
[ERR]           C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:120: javax.script.ScriptException: sun.
org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (<Unknown source>#22(eval)
#132) in <Unknown source>#22(eval) at line number 132
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:5
51)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)

[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:156)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:80)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.ant.AntCommand.execute(AntCommand.java:75)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:78)
[ERR]                   ... 31 more
[ERR]           Caused by: C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:120: javax.script.ScriptExce
ption: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (<Unknown sourc
e>#22(eval)#132) in <Unknown source>#22(eval) at line number 132
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.toBuildException(ReflectUtil.java:183)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.throwBuildException(ReflectUtil.java:166)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:110)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectWrapper.invoke(ReflectWrapper.java:81)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.evaluateScript(JavaxScriptRunn
er.java:103)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.executeScript(JavaxScriptRunne
r.java:67)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.script.ScriptDef.executeScript(ScriptDef.jav
a:350)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.script.ScriptDefBase.execute(ScriptDefBase.j
ava:50)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.
java:38)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
[ERR]                   ... 52 more
[ERR]           Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: Syntax
Error: unterminated string literal (<Unknown source>#22(eval)#132) in <Unknown source>#22(eval) at line number
 132
[ERR]                   at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:108)
[ERR]                   ... 69 more
[ERR]           Caused by: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: SyntaxError: unterminated string lit
eral (<Unknown source>#22(eval)#132)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.constructError(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.DefaultErrorReporter.error(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.addError(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.addError(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.addError(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.TokenStream.getToken(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.peekToken(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.assignExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.plainProperty(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.objectLiteral(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.primaryExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.memberExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.unaryExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   a
[ERR]           t sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.mulExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.addExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.shiftExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.relExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.eqExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.bitAndExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.bitXorExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.bitOrExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.andExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.orExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.condExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.assignExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.expr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.parenExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.primaryExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.memberExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.unaryExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.mulExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.addExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.shiftExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.relExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.eqExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.bitAndExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.bitXorExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.bitOrExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.andExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.orExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.condExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.assignExpr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.expr(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.statementHelper(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.statement(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context.compileImpl(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context.compileString(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.evalSpecial(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.callSpecial(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpret(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.call(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ContextFactory.doTopCall(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.superDoTopCall(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.doTopCall(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.exec(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context.evaluateReader(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   ... 77 more
[ERR]           Total time: 21 seconds

[ERR]           com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch\GS\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:120: javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.java
script.internal.EcmaError: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (<Unknown source>#22(eval)#132) in <Unknow
n source>#22(eval) at line number 132
```

With this type of error, how do I go about debugging it?  from what line do I start?

could anyone help with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Salam Mubarak,

it should be clear that you have missed to close a string value..

```
unterminated string literal (<Unknown source>#22(eval)#132) in <Unknown source>#22(eval) at line number 132
```

but what you can do is to go and search for all quotes in the system and check if they were closed...

Comment: Wa alikum alsalam wa rahmat ALLAH wa Brakatah Fahd, 

No, the problem is some extra comma which I added in there by mistake. Now, I can compile the app on my mac but the iOS simulator doesn't run after the compiling is finished (Well, it is supposed to be called after the build is finished)

I have checked the extension for the native iOS app that is just built for me through sencha command tools, it is .app??? but iOS devices accept .ipa